# SQL Scalar function element not recognized in TSQL program

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions

I have an input db2 table with two elements: loan_number, debt_to_income; this table's name is #Input_Table. I am trying to run a test the function by running a SQL program against this table. The problem is that the function's element is not being recognized in the SQL program for some reason, maybe I have been looking at to long? I need to validate that the output in the table will output in a order by the debt_to_income field.

Here is the function code:

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_DTI_BANDS]
(
    -- the parameters for the function here
    @FN_DTI_Band            decimal(4,3)
     )
RETURNS varchar(16)
AS
BEGIN

declare @Return varchar(16)

select @Return =

        Case
        when @FN_DTI_Band is NULL then ' Missing'
        WHEN @FN_DTI_Band = 00.00 then ' Missing'
        When @FN_DTI_Band < = 0.31 then 'Invalid'
        When @FN_DTI_Band between 0.31 and 0.34 then '31-34'
        When @FN_DTI_Band between 0.34 and 0.38 then '34-38'
        When @FN_DTI_Band >= 0.38 then '38+'
        else null end
            -- Return the result of the function
            RETURN @Return
END
```

Here is the T-SQL test program:

```
SELECT  loan_number,dbo.FN_DTI_BANDS(debt_to_income)as FN_DTI_Band

from #Input_table

SELECT      COUNT(*), FN_DTI_Band
FROM  #Input_table
GROUP BY FN_DTI_Band
ORDER BY FN_DTI_Band
```

Here is the error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'FN_DTI_Band'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'FN_DTI_Band'.
```

Can someone help me spot what I am overlooking? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table #input_table does not have a column called FN_DTI_Band.

Just the result of the first select statement has that column name.

You need to make the first select statement a sub query of the 2nd

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), T.FN_DTI_Band
FROM 
(
   SELECT  loan_number,dbo.FN_DTI_BANDS(debt_to_income) as FN_DTI_Band
   from #Input_table
) T
GROUP BY T.FN_DTI_Band
ORDER BY T.FN_DTI_Band
```

Comment: tried it and go a new error: Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. So I tried: use TEST
SELECT      COUNT(*), t.FN_DTI_BAND
 from 
 (

SELECT  loan_number,
        case when debt_to_income = 0 then 0 else
          dbo.FN_DTI_BANDS(debt_to_income)
          END as  FN_DTI_Band
  from #T2
 )T
 GROUP BY t.FN_DTI_Band
 ORDER BY t.FN_DTI_Band

still not quite right...

Comment: some of the data input rows have 0.0000 in the debt to income column

Comment: you can use a where in the select statement to take those out.

Comment: why do the conversion at all... just declare the parameter as numeric not decimal(4,3)

Comment: I just did not think of it, SQL is still somewhat new to me.. Thank you for pointing this out, most appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try prepending "dbo" onto the name of the function.

```
Select Count(*), dbo.FN_DTI_Band
From....
```